# Unique counts in elastic search for unique IDs

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say my data looks like this:

Documents for project 6000:

{"projectId": "6000", "price": 500000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Affordable luxury", "area": "A"},

{"projectId": "6000", "price": 700000, "bedrooms": 4, "title": "Spacious", "area": "A"}

Documents for project 6001:

{"projectId": "6001", "price": 550000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Stunning", "area": "A"}

{"projectId": "6001", "price": 650000, "bedrooms": 3, "title": "Excellent views". "area": "B"}

Documents for project 6002:

{"projectId": "6002", "price": 550000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Stunning", "area": "B"}

{"projectId": "6002", "price": 650000, "bedrooms": 3, "title": "Excellent views". "area": "C"}

and so on

Now, I want to retrieve counts of areas in order to get most popular areas where projects exist but consider only unique project IDs. I have this query:

```
    query = {
        "aggs": {
            "most_popular": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "area",
                    "size": 5,
                    "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                    },
                }
             }
          }
```

which results in :

buckets: [{'key': 'A', doc_count: 3}, {'key': 'B', doc_count: 2}...and so on]
But what I want is only unique count from each project so doc_count for A should be 2 instead of 3, i.e. avoid duplicates within the same project.

How is this possible in elasticsearch?

Comment: can you please share your expected search result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to use [bucket sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) that is a parent pipeline
> aggregation which sorts the buckets of its parent multi-bucket
> aggregation

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{"projectId": "6000", "price": 500000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Affordable luxury", "area": "A"},

{"projectId": "6000", "price": 700000, "bedrooms": 4, "title": "Spacious", "area": "A"}

{"projectId": "6001", "price": 550000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Stunning", "area": "A"}

{"projectId": "6001", "price": 650000, "bedrooms": 3, "title": "Excellent views". "area": "B"}

{"projectId": "6002", "price": 550000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Stunning", "area": "B"}

{"projectId": "6002", "price": 650000, "bedrooms": 3, "title": "Excellent views". "area": "C"}

{"projectId": "6002", "price": 500000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Affordable luxury", "area": "C"}

{"projectId": "6002", "price": 500000, "bedrooms": 2, "title": "Affordable luxury", "area": "C"}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "most_popular": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "area",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "projectId"
          }
        },
        "uniqueCount_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "unique": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"buckets": [
    {
      "key": "C",
      "doc_count": 3,
      "unique": {
        "value": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "B",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "unique": {
        "value": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "A",
      "doc_count": 3,
      "unique": {
        "value": 2
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @Srishti Rawal did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `aggregation` to your query and get **cardinality** of `projectId` like this:

```
{
        "aggs": {
            "most_popular": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "area",
                    "size": 5,
                    "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                    }
                },"aggs": {
                  "unique": {
                    "cardinality": {
                      "field": "projectId"
                    }
                  }
                }
             }
          }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the order by clause does not work as it should as I need it to be ordered by the unique value counts